# Action when an element from collection get scrolled by

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an unknown number of section blocks.
I use the titles of these automaticaly generated sections to populate the "tabs" container who follow the scroll (using `sticky` position).

What I need, is when I pass by one of the title contained in the sections, the same title from the "tabs" bar get the class `"selected"`so I indicate where the user is.

But what I've tried so far is only working partialy.
Here's a working example:

```js
let titles = [];
    $.each($('section>h3'),function(){
        titles.push($(this).offset().top);
    });
    $(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll',function(e){
    let winscrollpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        $.each(titles,function(i,v){
            if(winscrollpos >= v && winscrollpos < v+100) {
                $('.deco-tab-title').eq(i).add('.selected').toggleClass('selected');
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
.filler {
  height:800px;
}

.selected {
  color:red;
}

.tabs {
  background-color:#eee;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
}

p {
  width:200px
}

.tabs h3 {
  display:inline;
  margin-left:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='main'>
  <div class='filler'>
    
  </div>
  <div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='tabs'><h3 class='deco-tab-title selected'>title1</h3><h3 class='deco-tab-title'></h3><h3 class='deco-tab-title'>title2</h3><h3 class='deco-tab-title'>title3</h3><h3 class='deco-tab-title'>title4</h3></div>
  <div class='core'>
    <section>
      <h3 class='deco-tab-title'>title1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ligula sem, elementum a leo in, aliquam blandit orci. Ut scelerisque auctor tincidunt. Phasellus at dui eget nisl varius porttitor. Quisque fermentum nisi a quam consectetur, non malesuada urna maximus. Phasellus vehicula ante a felis molestie gravida vel ac augue. Duis ullamcorper malesuada nibh. Etiam non pulvinar ex. Proin rhoncus sagittis pulvinar. Suspendisse ac urna dui. Proin nec tempus augue, at molestie libero. Duis ut libero ut diam mollis pharetra et ac dui.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h3 class='deco-tab-title'>title2</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ligula sem, elementum a leo in, aliquam blandit orci. Ut scelerisque auctor tincidunt. Phasellus at dui eget nisl varius porttitor. Quisque fermentum nisi a quam consectetur, non malesuada urna maximus. Phasellus vehicula ante a felis molestie gravida vel ac augue. Duis ullamcorper malesuada nibh. Etiam non pulvinar ex. Proin rhoncus sagittis pulvinar. Suspendisse ac urna dui. Proin nec tempus augue, at molestie libero. Duis ut libero ut diam mollis pharetra et ac dui.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h3 class='deco-tab-title'>title3</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ligula sem, elementum a leo in, aliquam blandit orci. Ut scelerisque auctor tincidunt. Phasellus at dui eget nisl varius porttitor. Quisque fermentum nisi a quam consectetur, non malesuada urna maximus. Phasellus vehicula ante a felis molestie gravida vel ac augue. Duis ullamcorper malesuada nibh. Etiam non pulvinar ex. Proin rhoncus sagittis pulvinar. Suspendisse ac urna dui. Proin nec tempus augue, at molestie libero. Duis ut libero ut diam mollis pharetra et ac dui.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h3 class='deco-tab-title'>title4</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ligula sem, elementum a leo in, aliquam blandit orci. Ut scelerisque auctor tincidunt. Phasellus at dui eget nisl varius porttitor. Quisque fermentum nisi a quam consectetur, non malesuada urna maximus. Phasellus vehicula ante a felis molestie gravida vel ac augue. Duis ullamcorper malesuada nibh. Etiam non pulvinar ex. Proin rhoncus sagittis pulvinar. Suspendisse ac urna dui. Proin nec tempus augue, at molestie libero. Duis ut libero ut diam mollis pharetra et ac dui.</p>
    </section>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

as you can see, the first title lose the class if you scroll to the end. But nothing else. And when you go back, the second title get the class. And overall, it doesn't work so well.

Comment: I don't think you understand how sticky works. https://medium.com/@elad/css-position-sticky-how-it-really-works-54cd01dc2d46

Comment: @MelissaSkywalkz What makes you think that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You might want to use the `scroll` event, which also captures using the scroll bar.
2. Scrolling height depends on the user agent. You should compare 
   `[offset of current tab] < winscrollpos < offset[next tab]` instead of `[offset of current tab] < winscrollpos < offset[current tab] + 100`.

Here's a working demo:

```js
let titles = [];

$.each($('section>h3'), function () {
    titles.push($(this).offset().top);
});

$(document).on('scroll', function (e) {
    // 50 for the tab title height
    let winscrollpos = $(window).scrollTop() + 50;
    let titleElements = $('.deco-tab-title');
    $.each(titles, function (i, v) {
        if (winscrollpos >= v && (i === titles.length - 1 || winscrollpos < titles[i + 1])) {
            titleElements.eq(i).addClass('selected');
        } else {
            titleElements.eq(i).removeClass('selected');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.filler {
  height:800px;
}

.selected {
  color:red;
}

.tabs {
  background-color:#eee;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
}

p {
  width:200px
}

.tabs h3 {
  display:inline;
  margin-left:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='main'>
    <div class='filler'>
    
    </div>
    <div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='tabs'><h3 class='deco-tab-title selected'>title1</h3><h3 class='deco-tab-title'>title2</h3><h3 class='deco-tab-title'>title3</h3><h3 class='deco-tab-title'>title4</h3></div>
    <div class='core'>
    <section>
        <h3 class='deco-tab-title'>title1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ligula sem, elementum a leo in, aliquam blandit orci. Ut scelerisque auctor tincidunt. Phasellus at dui eget nisl varius porttitor. Quisque fermentum nisi a quam consectetur, non malesuada urna maximus. Phasellus vehicula ante a felis molestie gravida vel ac augue. Duis ullamcorper malesuada nibh. Etiam non pulvinar ex. Proin rhoncus sagittis pulvinar. Suspendisse ac urna dui. Proin nec tempus augue, at molestie libero. Duis ut libero ut diam mollis pharetra et ac dui.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h3 class='deco-tab-title'>title2</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ligula sem, elementum a leo in, aliquam blandit orci. Ut scelerisque auctor tincidunt. Phasellus at dui eget nisl varius porttitor. Quisque fermentum nisi a quam consectetur, non malesuada urna maximus. Phasellus vehicula ante a felis molestie gravida vel ac augue. Duis ullamcorper malesuada nibh. Etiam non pulvinar ex. Proin rhoncus sagittis pulvinar. Suspendisse ac urna dui. Proin nec tempus augue, at molestie libero. Duis ut libero ut diam mollis pharetra et ac dui.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h3 class='deco-tab-title'>title3</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ligula sem, elementum a leo in, aliquam blandit orci. Ut scelerisque auctor tincidunt. Phasellus at dui eget nisl varius porttitor. Quisque fermentum nisi a quam consectetur, non malesuada urna maximus. Phasellus vehicula ante a felis molestie gravida vel ac augue. Duis ullamcorper malesuada nibh. Etiam non pulvinar ex. Proin rhoncus sagittis pulvinar. Suspendisse ac urna dui. Proin nec tempus augue, at molestie libero. Duis ut libero ut diam mollis pharetra et ac dui.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h3 class='deco-tab-title'>title4</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ligula sem, elementum a leo in, aliquam blandit orci. Ut scelerisque auctor tincidunt. Phasellus at dui eget nisl varius porttitor. Quisque fermentum nisi a quam consectetur, non malesuada urna maximus. Phasellus vehicula ante a felis molestie gravida vel ac augue. Duis ullamcorper malesuada nibh. Etiam non pulvinar ex. Proin rhoncus sagittis pulvinar. Suspendisse ac urna dui. Proin nec tempus augue, at molestie libero. Duis ut libero ut diam mollis pharetra et ac dui.</p>
    </section>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, That's indeed the proper way :)

Answer (score 0):

I have made the following fixes in your code:

- `add('.selected').toggleClass('selected')`: chaining both functions this way cannot work. That's the reason why your titles were somehow blinking when selected. I've replaced this with the use of this version of [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state)
- I've added another list, `nextTitlePos`, in order to store, for each title, the position of the next one. For the last one, you can use any value greater than the end of your container (I've used `Number.MAX_VALUE` here to keep it simple, but if needed, you can use the end of the container as well.)
- In the HTML code, there was also an extra `<h3>` tag, which was empty. This one was preventing `title2` from being highlighted properly.
- EDIT: I've replaced the event `mousewheel` with `scroll` as well (as mentioned by Shridhar Sharma in a comment below - thanks)

```js
    let titles = [];
    $.each($('section>h3'),function(){
        titles.push($(this).offset().top);
    });
    let nextTitlePos = [];
    $.each(titles, function(i, v) {
          if(i != 0) {
              nextTitlePos.push(v);
          }
    }); 
    nextTitlePos.push(Number.MAX_VALUE);
    $(document).on('scroll DOMMouseScroll',function(e){
    let winscrollpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        $.each(titles,function(i,v){
            let isSelected = winscrollpos >= v && winscrollpos < nextTitlePos[i];
            $('div.tabs>h3.deco-tab-title').eq(i).toggleClass('selected', isSelected);
        });
    });
```

```css
.filler {
  height:800px;
}

.selected {
  color:red;
}

.tabs {
  background-color:#eee;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
}

p {
  width:200px
}

.tabs h3 {
  display:inline;
  margin-left:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='main'>
  <div class='filler'>
    
  </div>
  <div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='tabs'><h3 class='deco-tab-title selected'>title1</h3><!-- REMOVED <h3 class='deco-tab-title'></h3> --><h3 class='deco-tab-title'>title2</h3><h3 class='deco-tab-title'>title3</h3><h3 class='deco-tab-title'>title4</h3></div>
  <div class='core'>
    <section>
      <h3 class='deco-tab-title'>title1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ligula sem, elementum a leo in, aliquam blandit orci. Ut scelerisque auctor tincidunt. Phasellus at dui eget nisl varius porttitor. Quisque fermentum nisi a quam consectetur, non malesuada urna maximus. Phasellus vehicula ante a felis molestie gravida vel ac augue. Duis ullamcorper malesuada nibh. Etiam non pulvinar ex. Proin rhoncus sagittis pulvinar. Suspendisse ac urna dui. Proin nec tempus augue, at molestie libero. Duis ut libero ut diam mollis pharetra et ac dui.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h3 class='deco-tab-title'>title2</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ligula sem, elementum a leo in, aliquam blandit orci. Ut scelerisque auctor tincidunt. Phasellus at dui eget nisl varius porttitor. Quisque fermentum nisi a quam consectetur, non malesuada urna maximus. Phasellus vehicula ante a felis molestie gravida vel ac augue. Duis ullamcorper malesuada nibh. Etiam non pulvinar ex. Proin rhoncus sagittis pulvinar. Suspendisse ac urna dui. Proin nec tempus augue, at molestie libero. Duis ut libero ut diam mollis pharetra et ac dui.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h3 class='deco-tab-title'>title3</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ligula sem, elementum a leo in, aliquam blandit orci. Ut scelerisque auctor tincidunt. Phasellus at dui eget nisl varius porttitor. Quisque fermentum nisi a quam consectetur, non malesuada urna maximus. Phasellus vehicula ante a felis molestie gravida vel ac augue. Duis ullamcorper malesuada nibh. Etiam non pulvinar ex. Proin rhoncus sagittis pulvinar. Suspendisse ac urna dui. Proin nec tempus augue, at molestie libero. Duis ut libero ut diam mollis pharetra et ac dui.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h3 class='deco-tab-title'>title4</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ligula sem, elementum a leo in, aliquam blandit orci. Ut scelerisque auctor tincidunt. Phasellus at dui eget nisl varius porttitor. Quisque fermentum nisi a quam consectetur, non malesuada urna maximus. Phasellus vehicula ante a felis molestie gravida vel ac augue. Duis ullamcorper malesuada nibh. Etiam non pulvinar ex. Proin rhoncus sagittis pulvinar. Suspendisse ac urna dui. Proin nec tempus augue, at molestie libero. Duis ut libero ut diam mollis pharetra et ac dui.</p>
    </section>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It will not work when user scroll without the mouse wheel

Comment: You are right! We just need to replace the event `mousewheel` with `scroll`. I'm updating this above.

Comment: That is a good answer, but the ternary test and the 2nd array are way too much resources for an event that occure so often imo